# rails 3 Admin Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, admin

Whats wrong in my authentication i also dont know..can someone tell me what wrong?
i got user scaffold, and this is my admin controller

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
def login
if request.post?
  user = User.authenticate(params[:name], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid user/password combination"
  end
  end
  end

 def logout
session[:user_id] = nil
flash[:notice] = "Logged out"
redirect_to(:action => "login")
end

def index
end

end
```

and this is my admin/login.html.erb

```
 <div>
<%= form_tag do %>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Please Log In</legend>

  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
  </div>
   </fieldset>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

but when i try to log in using existence user it come like this

```
No route matches "/admin/login"
```

whats wrong with my code??am i missing something?

Comment: Do you have `resources :admin do; get 'login', :on => :member; end` in your routes.rb?

Comment: Can you paste up your routes.rb?

Comment: `Hawary::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :admin do; get 'login', :on => :member; end

  get "admin/login"

  get "admin/logout"

  get "admin/index"

  resources :users

  get "home/latest"

  resources :updates

  root :to => "home#index"

  get "home/index"

  get "home/about"

  get "home/activity"

  get "home/gallery"

  get "home/contact"

  resources :photos

  end `

Comment: Ok, remove what I suggested. Can you see any admin login path when you run `rake routes`?

Comment: yes i got it 
`  admin_login GET    /admin/login(.:format)      {:action=>"login", :controller=>"admin"}
 admin_logout GET    /admin/logout(.:format)     {:action=>"logout", :controller=>"admin"}
  admin_index GET    /admin/index(.:format)      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin"}
`

Comment: what if you change the line in the controller to `redirect_to admin_login_path`?

Comment: i changed it and come same result
`No route matches "/admin/login"`

Comment: same ><..hm maybe i should try another way..can suggest me simple authenticate just for admin?

Comment: this is my source i tried 
(http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR3/checkdepot-30/section-11.2.html), can suggest me another?

Comment: i think something was wrong with `<%= form_tag do %>`..any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that

```
Hawary::Application.routes.draw do
  post 'admin/login' => 'admin#login'
end
```